# harvard references latex in r sweave

Tags: r

I have the following problem download the LaTeX template, from the UNAL website.
[Descargar aquí la plantilla LaTeX](http://simposioestadistica.unal.edu.co/programacion-academica/comunicaciones/).

I understand that the template uses Harvard-style references. When using the template with Texmaker, it works correctly. But when using the template in R Sweave. In section 5."Citas bibliográficas".

```
Por ejemplo: \cite{Caballero-86}, \cite{Dodge-85}, \cite{Conover-81}, \cite{Searle-92}.
```

I get the following result:

```
Por ejemplo: (?), (?), (?), (?).
```

Which should be:

```
Por ejemplo: (Caballero 1986), (Dodge 1985), (Conover et al. 1981), (Searle et al. 1992).
```

The references section works correctly, as shown in the following image.
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G4qs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .bib file "symposium" there is a duplicate reference. Article "Borges-05" and "Borges-05",

```
@ARTICLE {Borges-05,
   AUTHOR = {Borges, R.},
   TITLE = {{Survival analysis of patients with peritoneal dialysis}},
   JOURNAL = {Revista Colombiana de Estadistica},
   YEAR = {2005},
   Volume = {28},
   Number = {2},
   Pages = {243-259},
}

@ARTICLE {Borges-05,
   AUTHOR = {Brown, M. and Forsythe},
   TITLE = {{Robust Test for the Equality of Variants}},
   JOURNAL = {Journal of the American Statistical Association}
   YEAR = {1974},
   Volume = {69},
   Number = {346},
   Pages = {364-367},
}
```

The problem of ? Is solved by eliminating the second reference.